# Task not working in Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, batch-file, taskscheduler

I have a PowerShell script that restarts our SMTP service when it's down. It looks like this:

```
$Computer = "localhost"
$SMTPServiceName = "SMTPSVC"
$AllServices = get-service -ComputerName $Computer
$SMTPService

foreach ($Service in $AllServices)
{
if ($Service.name -eq $SMTPServiceName)
{
    $SMTPService = $Service
    break
}
}

if ($SMTPService.status -eq "StopPending")
{
write-host "Service" $SMTPService "is pending stop. Attempting to stop and restart."
$servicePID = (gwmi win32_Service | where {$_.Name -eq $SMTPServiceName}).ProcessID
Stop-Process $ServicePID
Start-Service -InputObject (get-Service -ComputerName $Computer -Name $SMTPServiceName)
write-host "Service" $SMTPService "restarted."
}
elseif ($SMTPService.status -eq "Paused")
{
write-host "Service" $SMTPService "is paused. Attempting to resume."
Resume-Service -InputObject (get-Service -ComputerName $Computer -Name $SMTPServiceName)
write-host "Service" $SMTPService "resumed."
}
elseif ($SMTPService.status -eq "Stopped")
{
write-host "Service" $SMTPService "is stopped. Attempting to restart."
Start-Service -InputObject (get-Service -ComputerName $Computer -Name $SMTPServiceName)
write-host "Service" $SMTPService "restarted."
}
else
{
write-host "Service" $SMTPService "is running."
}
```

I've verified that this works. I shut the SMTP service down, run the script, and the SMTP service is back up and running.

The I created a .bat file for Task Scheduler to run. It looks like this:

```
cd "C:\Scripts\" & powershell.exe C:\Scripts\restart-smtp.ps1
```

I've verified that this works. I shut the SMTP service down, run the batch file, and the SMTP service is back up and running.

Now I want to get the Task Scheduler to run it every 5 minutes. I setup the task, point it to the batch file, but it doesn't work. I'm wondering if someone can help me troubleshoot this.

The only error I get is:

> The operator or administrator has refused the request. (0x800710E0)

I'm telling it to run as the same administrator that I log in as, the same administrator that runs the script and the batch file from the PowerShell prompt.

Here are my task settings:

[image]

One thing you might notice is that History is disabled. I'm wondering if I would see error logs in the history if it was enabled, but I'm not sure how to enable it.

This is running on Windows Server 2016.

Comment: Try enabling the 'Run with Highest Privileges' option

Comment: Did not work. Did not work.

Comment: Why don't you just configure your service to be automatically restarted by the Windows Service Control Manager?  Your SMTP server should be a demand started service anyway, there's no need for it to be running all the time.

Comment: Task Scheduler can run PowerShell directly, without starting cmd.exe.

Comment: This really is more of a [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) kind of problem.

Comment: This is NOT programming related.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers everyone, but I came up with a much simpler solution:

[image]